# Как создать один GUI для многих программ?

Tags: java, javafx

Я новичок в JavaFX. Создал приложение с тремя элементами: текстовое поле для ввода числа, кнопка "подтвердить" и лабель для отображения результата.

К кнопке "подтвердить" привязан слушатель, в теле которого и вычисляется результат по формуле.

Вопрос: как я могу использовать один этот графический интерфейс для многих приложений с другими формулами в теле слушателя? Конечно, можно просто скопировать и вставить код, переписав формулу в теле слушателя, но я ищу объектно-ориентированный метод.

Comment: Забить в программу несколько формул. К примеру в `HashMap`-у. Ключем будет название формулы, а значение какой-то класс с обработчиком данной формулы. Все обработчики будут иметь базовый тип, к примеру `Formula` и от него создавать классы `PriceFormula` и т.д.
На гуи создать `ComboBox` с выбором какой-то формулы. Если же в дальнейшем планируется добавлять поля, то тут уже сложнее будет. Я предполагаю что делать свои компоненты, которые сами знают свою формулу и свои поля.

Comment: сделать из этого подключаемую библиотеку. тогда везде, где нужна эта форма вы подключаете к проекту этот готовый модуль и используете его, как если бы он был в проекте, но для таких малых  как ваш пример,  не принято делать  библиотеку. Здесь более уместен сниппет, современные IDE позволяют сделать динамический шаблон, в котопом есть ниезменяемый код и участки, динамически подставляемые при использовании, вам нужно только ввести изменяемые параметры в окне использования и все, как File and code templates (для классов) или Live Templates (для методов и подобного внутри класса) в IDEA

Answer (score 1):

Можно создать абстрактный класс:

```
public abstract class MyPane extends Pane{

    private TextField textFld;
    private Button btn;
    private Label lbl;


    public MyPane(){

        textFld = new TextField();
        btn = new Button("ok");
        lbl = new Label("answer");

        this.getChildren().addAll(textFld,btn,lbl);

        btn.setOnAction(event->{

            String res = formula(textFld.getText());
            lbl.setText(res);
        });

    }

    protected abstract String formula(String text);
}
```

Далее наследуясь от этого класса, нужно будет переопределять для каждого наследника метод *formula(String val)*